# What is the difference between a microsoft visual c redistributable package and a runtime package?

Tags: c++, runtime

What is the difference between a Microsoft visual c++ 2010 redistributable package and a Runtime package? I could not find the install files for the Runtime visual c++ 2010.

Answer (score 7):

Its the redistributable package which include the run time. And at some places its called Runtime Redistributable.

> The Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package installs runtime
>   components of Visual C++ Libraries required to run applications
>   developed with Visual C++ on a computer that does not have Visual C++
>   2010 installed. This package installs runtime components of C Runtime (CRT), Standard C++, ATL, MFC, OpenMP and MSDIA libraries.

Ref: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14632

Comment: Hi Rohit, Thanks for the reply. I actually went through the link you mentioned above. But my question is in my control panel, I can see redistributable and runtime as different entries!  Any clue why there are two different thing

Comment: are you sure its the re distributable and runtime of Visual C++ of the same version?